# cUrl is returning JSON string, json_decode isn't decoding it to object or array

Tags: php, json, github-api

I'm using github's api to pull the most popular "starred" items under PHP, and it's pulling the json string ok. Only issue is my json_decode is still just dumping the JSON string and not an object. Below is the function I'm running.

```
private function fillTable(){
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL       => 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=+language:php&sort=stars&order=desc',
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'trickell'
));
$res = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump(json_decode($res));
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why it's not decoding the json string to an object. If you run this you should be able to see exactly what's pulling.

Comment: have you tried validating the string? Maybe it's not JSON at all

Comment: @Nordenheim GitHub will return invalid JSON?

Comment: @HankyPanky you have a valid point. No need to check the incoming data from any service ever then, I'll stop doing that too.

Comment: Not any service, but yeah for some service that big if it doesnt work its our code that doesnt work mostly. Not theirs

Answer (score 4):

Because you have **no** json to decode and that is because you are not telling cURL to return the value to you so you are trying to decode an empty string.

```
$res = curl_exec($curl);
```

That `$res` is going to be only **TRUE / FALSE** unless you ask for `RETURNTRANSFER`, as explained here

**[curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)**

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

So you have to add another option to your cURL call.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

You may ask then why are you seeing the JSON string if it is not being returned, this answers that question

**[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)**

> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() **instead of outputting it out directly**.

*(emphasis mine)*

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$post = ['batch_id'=> "2"];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://example.com/student_list.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($response);
$new=   $result->status;
if( $new =="1")
{
  echo "<script>alert('Student list')</script>";
}
else 
{
  echo "<script>alert('Not Removed')</script>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json'
        ));
```